# PHP SQL Form - How to pass a value to the next Select

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli

Hi I have manage to put this script together as a newbe. I have divided the script up in two parts each part works individually, but when putting it together and when I make the WHERE as a changeable value it won't work.

(the reason for the line in error everywhere/shortcode.php(15) is because its running on a php wordpress plugin, but as I say the to parts works individual)

Can someone tell me how I can pass that value

```
$myvalue
```

and open the connection in part two of the script, without getting error on the connection part. The value do get past to the varible but makes an error.

Here is the errors I get:

> Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/asports/public_html/calendar/wp-content/plugins/php-everywhere/shortcode.php(15) : eval()'d code on line 34
>
> Warning: mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/asports/public_html/calendar/wp-content/plugins/php-everywhere/shortcode.php(15) : eval()'d code on line 52
>
> ERROR: Could not able to execute SELECT men_slope FROM allcourses WHERE id='3'.
>
> Warning: mysqli_close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/asports/public_html/calendar/wp-content/plugins/php-everywhere/shortcode.php(15) : eval()'d code on line 56

// part one

```
<?php 
require_once(
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/calendar/courses/admin/connect.php'); 
?>
<form method=post>
<select name="myvalue">
<?php
// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT id, Name, color FROM allcourses";
$sql = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['Name'] . " (" . $row['color']. 
")" . "</option>";

}
// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
$myvalue=$_POST['myvalue'];
$myhdc=$_POST['hdc'];
?>
</select>
<br />
<p>Handicap: </p>
<input class="tex" type="text" name="hdc"\></input>

<br />

<input type=submit>
</form>
```

// Part two

```
<?php


// Attempt select query execution
$sqll = "SELECT men_slope FROM allcourses WHERE id='$myvalue'";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sqll)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
            
            echo "<td>" . $row['men_slope'] . "</td>";
            
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    
    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
} else{
    echo "No records matching your query were found.";
}
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sqll. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Don't call `mysqli_close($link);` in Part 1, you need it in Part 2.

Comment: that's it :D thank you for that.. please post it as an answer :)

Comment: I was so sure I had to close it before I made any new calls to the server :D

Comment: That's backwards. You close it *after* you're done making all your calls to the server.

Comment: You should parameterize your queries. This is open to SQL injections as is.

Comment: Thank you user3783243 I will look in to how to do that now :)

Comment: I rolled back your edit. The correct thing to do is just accept an answer (which you did). Please don't change the question so that it no longer makes sense.

Comment: okay only did it because I see so many doing it in there so thought it was how you did it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call `mysqli_close($link);` in Part One. Then when you try to perform a query in Part Two, the link is closed, so you can't use it any more.

IHMO, it's usually not important to call `mysqli_close()`. The connection will be closed automatically when the script ends. So unless your script runs for a long time after making all its database queries, it will not be idle for very long.

Comment: Thank you Barmar. and thank you for the explanation. I did come to the conclusion to use it because nearly everywhere you ready on the internet, everybody says it's so important to close the connection because for security matters :D